# All sockets receive messages except the first one

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I have a **react-native** project that uses **socket.io** to communicate with an express server.

On the server-side I have a handler that sends the total number of players in a certain room whenever a new socket joins the room:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  ...
  socket.on('initialConnectionResponse', (data) => {
      socket.join(data.roomCode);
      roomHandler.addPlayer(socket.id, data.name, data.roomCode);
      let playerCounter = roomHandler.getRoomCounter(data.roomCode);
      io.to(data.roomCode).emit('playerCounter', playerCounter);
  });
  ...
});
```

Now on the client-side, I have a state that updates every time a `playerCounter` event is received:

```
const [playerCount, setPlayerCount] = useState(0);
...
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  // Listen to PlayerCount event
  socket.on("playerCounter", data => {
      setPlayerCount(data);
  });
  ...
});

return (
  ...
  <Text>{`Current Players: ${playerCount}`}</Text>
  ...
)
```

So far so good? Now here is the problem, the very strange behavior I'm facing is that the first client doesn't receive the count updates of other players (except for itself), so its counter is frozen on the value **1**, always showing `Current Players: 1`, no matter how many other players join the room. However, all the other clients who joined after it receives these updates perfectly well, and update their counters whenever a new player joins.

So for illustration, here are the counter values of the clients on a typical scenario:

```
Client 1 joins:
  Client 1 counter: 1

Client 2 joins:
  Client 1 counter: 1
  Client 2 counter: 2

Client 3 joins:
  Client 1 counter: 1
  Client 2 counter: 3
  Client 3 counter: 3
```

What would cause such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of investigation, it turned out that the first socket that always came from a `createRoom` component, joined a room with a 5-digit numeric code (eg. 13586), while every following socket that always came from a `joinRoom` component joined the string equivalent room for this code (eg. "13586").

The problem wouldn't have existed if I was using TypeScript, or if I did a simple type-checking myself.